# Does the Jersey 1.19 required JavaSE1.7?

Tags: java, tomcat, jersey

I have to deploy a Restful service on two PCs. One PC is windows XP system so that it's java environment is JAVA 6.I developed my service with Jersey 1.19 and test it on my own PC which has Java 8.  When I test it on XP, the tomcat startup.bat show me that it cannot find root resources classes.Is the Jersey 1.19 requring Java 7 caused this?

Comment: The [documentation for Jersey 1.19.1](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/1.19.1/chapter_deps.html) says that Java SE 6 or newer is required, not Java 7. So no, that is most likely not the cause of your error. However, if you compile your code with Java 8 you must at least use the `-source` and `-target` options to make it compatible with Java 6, and not use any new API that was not available in Java 6.

Comment: thank you so much.I will check my project again

Comment: I change them to 1.6,but it doesn't work